# Group action on coset space is continuous

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology

I found this exercise in various places, but I could not find the answer anywhere. As I am quite new to topology, I would appreciate any help.

Let $G$ a topological group and $H$ a subgroup. Let the coset space $G/H$ be equipped with the quotient topology (that is, $U\subseteq G/H$ is defined as open, iff $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is open, $\pi:G\to G/H$ being the natural projection).

**Show that:** The group action of $G$ on $G/H$ is continuous, which means that the map $G\times G/H\to G/H, (g,xH)\mapsto gxH$ is continuous.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Use the continuity of group multiplication and $\pi$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Mambo mentioned, the group operation and $\pi$ are continuous by definition. Therefore, the map $\phi: G\times G \to G/H, (x,y)\mapsto xyH$ is continuous as a composition of the group operation an $\pi$. Hence, the preimage $\phi^{-1}(U)$ of any open set $U\subseteq G/H$ is open in $G\times G$.

But $\pi$ [is an open map](https://simomaths.wordpress.com/2013/03/23/topology-quotients-of-topological-groups/), so $\psi=(id,\pi): G\times G \to G\times G/H, (x,y)\mapsto (x,yH)$ is also an open map. So if we can show, that $\psi(\phi^{-1}(U))$ equals the preimage of $U$ under the group action of $G$ on $G/H$ (call this set $M$), we're done.

This holds because:
$$\psi(\phi^{-1}(U))=\psi(\{(x,y)\in G\times G\ |\ xyH\in U\})=\{(x,yH)\in G\times G/H\ |\ xyH\in U\}=M$$

Therefore, the preimage of an open set under the $G$-operation is open, which shows that the $G$-operation on $G/H$ is continuous.

Comment: This is the proof that I could come up with, following Mambo's hint, and the link in the text. If there are alternative proofs or corrections for this one, I would be interested to see them.